# Purely cognitive, as opposed to neuropsychological, characterizations of schizophrenia

Tags: cognitive-psychology, schizophrenia

Has anyone attempted to characterize schizophrenia purely by particular patterns in the way they think, based on the things they say? I mean for example, looking at a lot of recorded data of things they have said or written, in response to questions, or observations, to try to detect patterns in cognition, beyond the general "disorderly thinking", as I think a diagnostic manual describes it as. I think I read in a book by Robert Sapolsky that one more specific example of the highly specific "texture" of schizophrenic consciousness/thought is "concretization", which is apparently a certain way schizophrenics respond to questions involving some abstract entity, which they interpret in a counterintuitively "concrete" way. More generally, I'd like to know if we know or can predict specifically what kind of "disorderly thinking" a schizophrenic person might say, and what they would not be likely to say, and why. In purely cognitive (and non-neural) terms, do we observe any interesting patterns?